# Django: Accesing User fields from a filter in a ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-models, django-users

I want to fill a choice field with users who are not staff. I am using an extended user class (with a OneToOneField as mentioned in django docs):

```
class Usuario(models.Model):
    user =  models.OneToOneField (User)    
    departamento   = models.ForeignKey(Departamento, null=True)
```

Then,

```
class Proyecto(models.Model):
    ip = models.ForeignKey(Usuario, limit_choices_to = {'user.is_staff__exact': False },  related_name='pr_ip') # not working!
    jp = models.ForeignKey(Usuario, limit_choices_to = {'departamento__isnull': False },   related_name='pr_jp') # works!
```

The problem is that I cannot use user.is_staff field to filter. Any idea about how to fix this or how to do it?

Comment: If you use "user__is_staff__exact" this works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a double underscore instead:

```
'user__is_staff__exact': False
```